# Multi-line input reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, user-interface

I wrote two functions to read multi-line user input.

```
from os import linesep


def input_lines(prompt=None):
    """Yields input lines from user until EOFError is raised."""

    while True:
        try:
            yield input() if prompt is None else input(prompt)
        except EOFError:
            break
        else:
            prompt = None   # Only display prompt while reading first line.


def multiline_input(prompt=None):
    """Reads a multi-line input from the user."""

    return linesep.join(input_lines(prompt=prompt))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(multiline_input('Gimme your lines: '))
```

Is there something I can improve by maybe invoking some library method I overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much code, however, I'd change `input_lines` in the following ways:

- > Only display prompt while reading first line.

  If you're only going to do something once, then just add it as an initial return.
- It's simpler IMO to have a `try` that wraps the entire code of the function, this way you know it will keep doing something until `EOFError` is raised. Rather than possibly do something on each iteration.

  As noted in the comments by OP, you can instead use [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress), which can make the code easier to read.
- You may want to use `yield from` and `iter`, if you think that's cleaner to read than a while loop.

This can result in either of:

```
def input_lines(prompt=None):
    try:
        if prompt is not None:
            yield input(prompt)
        while True:
            yield input()
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

```
from contextlib import suppress


def input_lines(prompt=None):
    with suppress(EOFError):
        if prompt is not None:
            yield input(prompt)
        yield from iter(input, None)
```